# What is the point of Integer.BYTES in Java?

Tags: java, integer, byte

I couldn't find this question being asked so I had to ask it.

Java doc says:

> The number of bytes used to represent a int value in two's complement binary form.

Why would we use this in Java? I know what two's complement binary form is, but I cannot wrap my head around its usage.

I found this specifically in Tim Buchalka's course, but he struggled to explain it properly.
The code where he used it is:

```
int locationStart = (int) (indexSize + rao.getFilePointer() + Integer.BYTES);
```

It's used in RandomAccessFile lesson. I saw other tutors explaining RAF without using Integer.BYTES.

Comment: Well, it's a constant that basically says an `int` needs 4 bytes. You could use a magic number in your code or use that more descriptive constant. Assume you open a RAF which only contains ints and want to position the cursor at the 5th int. You could position the cursor at byte offset `4 * 4` or at `4 * Integer.BYTES`. The former may be shorter but the latter is easier to read and maintain. - To make it clear: that constant is not related to random access files per se but to byte streams/arrays that contain binary `int` data.

Answer (score 1):

The way you have `Integer.MAX_VALUE` to represent a number that holds the maximum value an int can have, which is `231-1` or `2147483647`, you have `Integer.BYTES` to represent a number that holds the number of bytes an `int` uses, which is `4`. It's less error-prone and easier to maintain your code using named constants than using the values themselves.

[This page](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.lang.Integer.BYTES) presents many such constant values.

Answer (score 0):

As of my understanding the JavaDoc's comment part "[...]number of bytes used to represent int[...]" is the importent part here, not that two's complement is used. Since Integer is a Object representation of the primitive type int, it provides you some more information about the Integer/int type, like `Integer.BYTES` = 4 or `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, `Integer.MIN_VALUE`.

Java has eight primitive data types [see JavaDoc on primitive types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html).
All of their Object representations provide this constant for you to know how much memory will be used to store the value of a variable of that type. Like `Short.BYTES` = 2, `Long.BYTES` = 8 and so on.